# How can I extract links from an HTML file with Perl?

Tags: perl, excel

I have some input with a link and I want to open that link. For instance, I have an HTML file and want to find all links in the file and open their contents in an Excel spreadsheet.

Comment: Why oh why must each of your posts be formatted like that? Why?

Comment: Are you asking how to get a list of links from some html file? Or are you asking how to follow the links? Or are you asking how to get something into an Excel spreadsheet?

Comment: The way I read it he/she wants to scrape data from pages that are linked from a given page and put the results in Excel documents.

Comment: i want to open the links and read its contents in a html file.

Answer (score 5):

It sounds like you want the linktractor script from my [HTML::SimpleLinkExtor](http://search.cpan.org/dist/HTML-SimpleLinkExtor) module.

You might also be interested in my [webreaper](http://search.cpan.org/dist/webreaper/) script. I wrote that a long, long time ago to do something close to this same task. I don't really recommend it because other tools are much better now, but you can at least look at the code.

[CPAN](http://search.cpan.org/) and [Google](http://www.google.com) are your friends. :)

[Mojo::UserAgent](http://www.metacpan.org/module/Mojo::UserAgent) is quite nice for this, too:

```
use Mojo::UserAgent

print Mojo::UserAgent
    ->new
    ->get( $ARGV[0] )
    ->res
    ->dom->find( "a" )
    ->map( attr => "href" )
    ->join( "\n" );
```

Answer (score 1):

That sounds like a job for [WWW::Mechanize](http://search.cpan.org/dist/WWW-Mechanize/lib/WWW/Mechanize.pm). It provides a fairly high level interface to fetching and studying web pages.

Once you've read the docs, I think you'll have a good idea how to go about it.

Comment: use WWW::Mechanize;

    my $mech = WWW::Mechanize->new( autocheck => 1 );

$mech->get( "http://www.google.com" );
print $mech->content;


GETTING ERROR

Error GETing http://www.google.com: Can't connect to www.google.com:80 (connect:Unknown error)

I WANT TO KNOW WHAT IS WRONG.

Comment: google.com is special. It doesn't like robots. However, it sounds like you have a network issue if you can't even connect.

Answer (score 1):

There is also [Web::Query](http://metacpan.org/releases/Web-Query):

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl 

use 5.10.0;

use strict;
use warnings;

use Web::Query;

say for wq( shift )->find('a')->attr('href');
```

Or, from the cli:

```
$ perl -MWeb::Query -E'say for wq(shift)->find("a")->attr("href")' \
       http://techblog.babyl.ca
```

Answer (score 0):

I've used [URI::Find](https://metacpan.org/pod/release/MSCHWERN/URI-Find-20140709/lib/URI/Find.pm) for this in the past (for when the file is not HTML).